# initialize angular on window.onload

Tags: angularjs, onload

How can i make my angular app work when running the angular initialisation code in the window onload event

PS : the code in comment works, the code in the onload event doesn't...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/angular.js/1.4.0-beta.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <!--script>
     angular.module('dropboxApp', [])
            .controller('dropboxController', function () {
                var dropbox = this;
                dropbox.label = 'hello angular';
            });
    </script-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload=function() { 
      angular.module('dropboxApp', [])
            .controller('dropboxController', function () {
                var dropbox = this;
                dropbox.label = 'hello angular';
            });}
      </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="dropboxApp" ng-controller="dropboxController as dropbox">
    {{dropbox.label}}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look on my fix for your example in IIFE style:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/17n7pxhb/)

```
<script>
  window.onload=(function (angular) { 
  angular.module('dropboxApp', [])
        .controller('dropboxController', function () {
            var dropbox = this;
            dropbox.label = 'hello angular';
        });})(window.angular);
  </script>
```

But I really really really don't suggest you to use window.onload for this purposes. It's really better to use [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). And if you're worried about some content, which isn't loaded until page is ready, you can use [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Comment: Although the answer above works correctly, i can't alter the onload to use IIFE, see also this new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352773/initialize-angular-on-window-onload-event